# Facebook signed request decoding hash does not appear to match exactly

Tags: java, facebook

I'm working with Facebook and parsing the signed request in a Java servlet using Sun Base64 decoder. I'm getting signature failures, although the signature appears to *nearly* match. What I can't figure out is why it doesn't match exactly, and I believe it's got to be a problem with my code. The minimum code to see what I'm doing:

```
BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
String[] parts = request.getParameter("signed_request").split("\\.", 2);
String signature = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(parts[0]), "UTF-8");
String rawData = new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(parts[1]), "UTF-8");

if (!isSignedRequestValid(request, obj, signature, parts[1]))
...

    private boolean isSignedRequestValid(HttpServletRequest request, JSONObject obj, String signature, String data) throws IOException
    {

            String expectedSignature = generateSha256Signature(data, FacebookAppSecretKey);

            if (!signature.equals(expectedSignature))
            {
                log("Facebook signatures do not match, expected: " + expectedSignature + ", received: " + signature);
                return false;
            }
         }


    private String generateSha256Signature(String data, String key) throws Exception
    {
      java.net.URLDecoder decoder = new java.net.URLDecoder();
      data = decoder.decode(data, "UTF-8");  // mostly here for testing, doesn't seem to make a difference
        SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
        mac.init(secretKey);
        byte[] hmacData = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        return new String(hmacData);
    }
```

I run into two problems... first, the expected vs provided signatures are 32 vs. 33 bytes. But if I compare just the first 32 bytes, sometimes they are equal, but when it doesn't match, it doesn't match by exactly one bit. For example, printing out the indexes and values one example is:

```
index 14 : [15] , [15]
index 15 : [71] , [71]
index 16 : [-10] , [-26]    <-- note the different here, which is 16, or one bit
index 17 : [28] , [28]
index 18 : [60] , [60]
```

I'm new to parsing Facebook requests, so I have to believe there's something I missed in the code, but I'm not seeing it, and have played around with it long enough to need help. And I'm not seeing an answer anywhere else online.
Thanks!

Comment: You cannot parse arbitary bytes (such as SHA hashes) as UTF8.

Comment: I don't think that was it. I changed to be all byte arrays by just using decoder.decodeBuffer(), returns byte array, and comparing that to hmacData which is a byte array. It turns out they have different lengths, 32 vs. 33. The one I generate from the generate signature method is 32 bytes. The one I get from facebook in the signed request is 33 bytes. This makes me wonder if the decoder function has an error. Also, it appears to depend on the data. If I run it several times, sometimes it compares correctly (comparing the first 32 bytes), sometimes not. So something in the data seems to matter.

Comment: I wonder if it has to do with space to + conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two problems... first, the decode of the provided Facebook signature decodes to 33 bytes instead of 32. So I just use the first 32 bytes (don't really care what that last one is... just a function of padding, I guess).

The other problem was the URL encoding of + to -. Using URLDecoder to decode the Facebook signature before base 64 decoding didn't solve the problem. Instead, I did this:

```
    BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
    String[] parts = request.getParameter("signed_request").split("\\.", 2);
    String rawSig = parts[0];
    rawSig = rawSig.replaceAll("\\-", "\\+");
    byte[] signature = decoder.decodeBuffer(rawSig);
```

and that was sufficient such that the first 32 bits now always match the computed signature. I find it odd that the URL encoding was done in such a way that URLDecoder.decode() didn't fix it. Would certainly be curious if anyone has any insight into that reason.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you also have to sub `_` to become `/`

Found a thing [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications):

> modified Base64 for URL variants exist, where the '+' and '/' characters of standard Base64 are respectively replaced by '-' and '_',